# how to remove unwanted character from a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just trying t find the proper solution for my scenario. Say I have a list of 2 elements, as shown below:

```
old_str = ['https://www[dot]exabeam[dot]com','https://www[dot]google[dot]com/#q=exa+beam']
```

I want output as `['www.exabeam.com', 'www.google.com']`

I can very well use the below logic to replace '[dot]' with '.'

```
new_str= []
for new_char in old_str:
    replaced_str = new_char.replace('[dot]', '.')
    new_str.append(replaced_str)
print(new_str)
```

the output is :

```
[['https://www.exabeam.com'], ['https://www.google.com/#q=exa+beam']]
```

So, how to achieve the expected output? Please help

Thank you

Comment: is it always 'https://' ?

Comment: yes,anyway @Chris's solution works like charm. thank you

Comment: The output you show is incorrect and the code you show has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: Hi, yes, I know. I mean I have to do my investigation before I ask a question. So, thats what I did, and I know my program is inefficient. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

[urlparse(i.replace("[dot]", ".")).netloc for i in old_str]
```

Output:

```
['www.exabeam.com', 'www.google.com']
```